# Grabbing A Page from WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

1. In WordPress, how do I hide a Page?
2. How do I then reimplement it as a DIV, let's say, on another Page?

**Context**

I'm trying to get some year-end tax write-offs here for my freelance business, and so I'm donating WordPress sites to churches. Now, unfortunately I'm finding that several pastors don't understand computers that well, and even though WordPress is fairly easy to tech guys like you and me, they get a bit confused. Therefore, I commented out Posts, Comments, Plugins, Widgets, Users, Design, and left nothing but Pages (New, Edit, Delete) and Media Gallery. I then took a theme that showed the Pages as tabs at the top like a normal website.

My hope is to call a particular page like Sidebar1 as its title. However, instead of this being displayed as a tab, it will be hidden. Then, it will be reimplemented as a DIV inside the page titled Home. If the pastor accidentally deletes Sidebar1, all he has to do is recreate it again and poof it reappears.

This doesn't deal with the Wordpress website, but the Wordpress installation.

I've changed the admin -- I just need to change the front-end.

I could figure this out on my own, but in the interest of time I wondered if someone had already done this?

Your help could help me get this done just in time for Christmas for some area churches here. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but just to be clear, you're modifying the actual WordPress interface, not modifying a WordPress-driven page, correct?

Comment: Not the Wordpress site, but a Wordpress installation.

I've already modified the admin and I can stop with that now. I just need to modify the front-end part that displays the pages.

Answer (score 3):

*Someone named 'greyhoundcode' in another forum answered me, so I thought I'd post it here.*

*His response...*

If, for example, you have four pages:

1. Home
2. About
3. Sidebar
4. Contact

And you deliberately wish to exclude the Sidebar page from being part of the page navigation, you can exclude it like so:

```
wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&exclude=3&title_li=');
```

You can retrieve it on the page where you want to drop it in with a wp_query statement.

*...This is exactly what I needed.*

Answer (score 1):

I think the most logical way is to customize the theme.  The theme system is sophisticated and could easily handle such a thing, I believe.  At least if I understand the problem.

Be careful with modifying the core system, though.  WordPress is known to release new security fixes very often.